# How to set local files package of appv 5.1 on a server

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, appv

I have to install and configure `Microsoft Application Virtualization v5.1` (known as `appv 5.1`). I have already installed the server side on a `WS2012R2` (SQL is on too), the sequencer and client are on `W10` and my domain controller is on a `WS2016`.

I have deployed tiny packages like `Python3` and `Notepad++` but they have local files stored at AppData and maybe at others folders.

Then I don't know how to store those local files on directories server to avoid file overflow.

My goal is to have a different directory for every users where application files related are stored.

Could you please explain me how to do this ?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

You have not grasped quite how the App-V infrastructure and client works yet. What you want is not possible and not something you actually want.

All packages local to one client (be in RDS-server or Win10 machine) are stored in one location and shared. There is however a "cache" that is layered on top of the package for every user. This is stored under AppData and in the registry, per user.

I advice you read up on the basic App-V infrastructure and how App-V works.

[Here](http://www.tmurgent.com/TmBlog/?p=2482) is one place to get started.

https://www.appvirtguru.com/ has some good resources on design etc.

http://www.tmurgent.com/appv/en/ has info on all versions, and many other resources.